# How to overwrite toString function in javascript when using the dynamic prototype pattern?

Tags: javascript, prototype

The dynamic prototype pattern checks to see if a function already exists on a class before binding it to the class. This is an issue because toString is already a method on the class by default. How can I work around this?

```
myClass = funciton () {

    if(typeof this.toString !== "function") {
        myClass.prototype.toString = function () {
            return "This is the output of my custom toString method";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assign a function: `myClass.prototype.toString = function(){...}`

Comment: So instead of dynamically adding it by type checking I should just add it? I guess that makes sense because the function is already there so I might as well just add it

Comment: If you worry about inherited properties, use `.hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: I guess you meant `typeof myClass.prototype.toString`?

Comment: Just edited to use the prototype properly as seen here http://john-dugan.com/object-oriented-javascript-pattern-comparison/

Comment: Shouldn't it be `function`?

Comment: edited again. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Don't add methods to the prototype inside the constructor. Do it only once, outside.